# Does dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime include/need dotnet.exe

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm confused as to whether or not I need the dotnet core SDK to use "dotnet" as an entry point for my docker container.

Current my docker file looks like the following code...

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "***.***.dll"]
```

Having trouble currently but at some point I'm pretty sure I'll get it to work. I'm just curious here.

Comment: `dotnet` isn't a single exe (afaik). `dotnet run` is supplied by the runtime installation of .NET Core and `dotnet build` is supplied by the SDK. If you need to use `dotnet build` (or other build-like commands), then you need to install the SDK. But if all you need is `dotnet run`, then  you should install the runtime.

Comment: `dotnet run` is also an SDK command - it builds a csproj/vbproj/fsproj and runs the output. if you already have an output, you only use the host executable (`dotnet`) and point it to the .dll file.